# The command Get-InstalledApps doesn't work (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to list all the apps and programs installed on my computer. The comand Get-InstalledApps it's supossed to work but I get this response:

```
Get-InstalledApps : El término 'Get-InstalledApps' no se reconoce como nombre de
un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si
escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que
dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Get-InstalledApps
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-InstalledApps:String) [], Com
   mandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have already tried to google it, but i'm not capable of solving it.

Comment: there is NO such command in powershell. [*grin*] have you tried >>> `Get-Command *installed*` <<< yet? that would appear to be a custom cmdlet or function that someone wrote ... and that you have failed to install.

Comment: This isn't a built-in cmdlet.  A big clue here is that the 'InstalledApps' is plural, which is against the PowerShell naming standard, so is probably not a Microsoft thing.  You'll need to install the cmdlet first.  A quick search found this script that might be what your looking for: [Get-InstalledApps.ps1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DosInstallUtilities/1.0.210.0/Content/internal%5CGet-InstalledApps.ps1)